# TeeChart package name to use for free versus paid product options

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a Delphi package DPK file which I ship to customers (WebHub customers), and that requires the use of the 'tee' package -- the free one that is included with Delphi.

```
 requires
   vcl, vclx, vcldb,
   {$IFNDEF Delphi12UP}vcljpg, {$ENDIF}  // in D07 and D11 but not in D12
   dsnap, dbexpress, dbxcds,
   tee,  // this is the problem/question: what package should be here, when?
   ldiRegExLib, ZaphodsMapLib, WebHub;
```

When my customers buy the paid version of TeeChart, they end up with different packages names, with variations for FireMonkey, ios and VCL.  All wonderful.  My question is: can I determine (from an include file, from a registry setting, from something that the TeeChart installer controls) which package name I should reference? I am only asking about VCL.  If I can be sure which package name, then I can tweak something during install such that the correct package(s) are included.
In my pas source, my uses clause has this already:

```
 {$IFDEF Delphi16UP} VclTee.Chart, VclTee.Series, {$ELSE} Chart, Series, {$ENDIF}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The packages you are basically need use, without FMX are:

Tee916.bpl: Always necessary.

TeeDB916.bpl: Use it if you want work with DBChart,but if you don't use DBChart you not need included this package.

TeeGL916.bpl: Use it if you want work with GL canvas, but if you don't use GL canvas you not need included this package.

TeeImage916.bpl: Always necessary.

TeeLanguage916.bpl:Always necessary.

TeeMaker116.bpl: Use it if you want work with TeeMaker, but  if you don't use TeeMaker you not need included this package.

TeePro916.bpl: Always necessary.

TeeTree2D16Tee9.bpl: Use it if you want work with TeeTree, but if you don't use TeeTree you not need included this package.

TeeUI916.bpl: Always necessary.

TeeWorld916.bpl: Use it if you want work with TeeWorld, if you don't use TeeWorld you not need included this package.

If you remove essential packages, you can make smallest the project and reducing his size.

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Best Regards,
Sandra Pazos

Steema Support Central
http://support.steema.com/

Comment: This is the upshot. When the free TeeChart is used, the package name "Tee" works due to LibSuffix. In XE2, "Tee" automatically becomes "Tee9160".  The trailing 0 indicates the free TeeChart package incl. w/ XE2. When the Pro TeeChart is used, the package name must be listed as "Tee916" for v9 within D16 aka XE2. The way to tell which is installed is: ask the user or climb in the registry and review Known Packages.  If component packages were installed, prior to paid TeeChart, and those packages used "Tee", then there will be a conflict until they are uninstalled and rebuilt with "Tee916".